# How to find if part of string belongs to a List

Tags: c#, string, list, linq

I have list as follows:

```
 readonly List<string> carMake = new List<string>
        {
            "Toyota",
            "Honda",
            "Audi",
            "Tesla"
        };
```

I have a string at runtime which is as follows:

```
string strOutput = "Project1:Toyota:Corolla";
```

Now, I will like to use strOutput and carMake to make sure the string as correct car make. How do I do this using Linq?

I want to:

- **return true** when strOutput = "Project1:Toyota:Corolla" (as Toyota is in list)
- **return false** when strOutput = "Project1:Foo:Corolla" (as Foo is not in the list)

Comment: I'd parse the string to an object (or at least a tuple) first, and then use a property of the object for the check after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method with a predicate to check if any of the strings in the `carMake` list is contained inside the `strOutput`:

```
return carMake.Any(i => strOutput.Contains(i));
```

OR, if your runtime string will always be in that format, you can split by ':' and compare to the value in the middle:

```
string runtimeValue = strOutput.Split(':')[1];
return carMake.Contains(runtimeValue);
```

Comment: For accuracy, he could also split by ":", and compare for the second string in the car make array

Comment: Indeed he could. I'm going to edit my answer and include it.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> carMake = new List<string> { "Toyota", "Honda", "Audi", "Tesla" };
string strOutput = "Project1:Toyota:Corolla";

string carBrand = strOutput.Split(':')[1];

bool result = carMake.Contains(carBrand);
```